# axios post 405 not allowed | Laravel + vue.js

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, post, axios

I can't create new database record, because after submit it always shows POST 405 (not allowed). I tried to move laravel routes from api.php to web.php but it didn't work. Also tried to modificate axios.post link (create, /create, localhost://Reservationsystem/public/create) but it also didn't gave me result.

Web.php

```
Route::resource('/reservation','ReservationController');
Route::get('/{any}', 'SinglePageController@index')->where('any', '.*');
```

Routes.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import Home from './components/HomeComponent.vue'
import Reservations from './components/ReservationsComponent.vue'

Vue.use(Router);

export default new Router({
    routes: [
        {
            path: '/',
            name: 'home',
            component: Home
        },
        {
            path: '/reservations',
            name: 'reservations',
            component: Reservations
        }
    ]
})
```

HomeComponent.vue

```
<script>
    import axios from 'axios';

    export default {
        data: function () {
            return {
                reservation: {
                    name: '',
                    surname: '',
                    email: '',
                    date: '',
                    place: ''
                }
            }
        },
        methods: {
            addReservation: function () {
                let uri = 'reservation';
                axios.post(uri, this.reservation).then(res => this.reservation = [...this.reservation, res.data]);
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

controller method:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $reservation= new Reservation($request->all());
    $reservation->save();

    return new ReservationResource($reservation);
}
```

Comment: Please include code in the controller. Do you have a `public function store`?

Comment: Yes. Method is added now

Comment: Try leaving the route `Route::resource('/reservation','ReservationController');` in `api.php` and make the axios call to `/api/reservation` url.

Comment: Please check you network tab when making the call. What is the full url the call is going to (in the network tab)?

Comment: When I tried to access post method url it shows me blank page, it was strange and after some researches I found that after public in url I need to add index.php (localhost/project/public/index.php/...) it seems to be server configuration problem..

Answer (score 1):

The reason you may be getting 405 is because the route is not Post to coincide with post in the addReservation  method.I would use the following for the post route:

```
Route::post('/reservation/store','ReservationController@store');
```

for the uri in axios I would use:

```
let uri = 'reservation/store';
```

Here is a link to a post showing how I used axios with Laravel.
[Blog Post With Code](https://david.dukesnuz.com/blog/21/Website%20Development/using-axios-in-a-vuejs-component-in-a-laravel-app)

Answer (score 0):

Yo you use https? If yes, do not use `/` in end of address.